# Why doesn't echo called as /bin/sh -c echo foo output anything?

Tags: shell, command-line, arguments, echo

For example, while this works:

```
$ echo foo
foo
```

This doesn't:

```
$ /bin/sh -c echo foo
```

Whereas this does:

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo foo; echo bar'
foo
bar
```

Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From `man sh`

```
-c string   If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. 
            If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the
            positional parameters, starting with $0
```

It means your command should be like this:

```
 $ sh -c 'echo "$0"' foo 
 foo
```

Similarly:

```
$ sh -c 'echo "$0 $1"' foo bar
foo bar
```

That was the first part to understand; the second case is simple and doesn't need explanation, I guess.

Comment: A stricter, standard conformant way would be `sh -c 'echo $1' echo foo`

Comment: `sh -c 'echo "$@"' fnord a b c d ...`

Comment: IMHO the explanation was quite good, but `sh -c 'echo $0' foo` is not the best option, taking into account that the questioner already know that `/bin/sh -c 'echo foo; echo bar'` works, you can simply answer quoting the command `/bin/sh -c 'echo foo'`

Comment: @ X3MBoy The questioner already know that /bin/sh -c 'echo foo' works fine. He wanted to echo something outside that , which i explained

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan what if I want to execute some command with sh -c something like this:    sh -c test.py arg1 arg2 arg3  ?  Secondly what if arg3 contains something like "/export/local/repo/ab#cd.rpm" , how can I handle # in this case ?

Answer (score 19):

```
$ echo foo
foo
```

This calls `echo` with the argument *foo* and *foo* is printed.

```
$ /bin/sh -c echo foo
```

This invokes the shell with the argument `echo` and provides *foo* as argument
`$0`. The `echo` outputs a new line and you discard the *foo*. If you want to
output *foo*, quote the argument:

```
sh -c 'echo foo'
```

or use the provided argument:

```
sh -c 'echo $0' foo
```

In this example

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo foo; echo bar'
foo
bar
```

The shell is invoked with the argument `echo foo; echo bar` which outputs

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 8):

In this command:

```
echo foo
```

`echo` is the binary (or built-in command) and `foo` is the first argument.

Here:

```
/bin/sh -c echo foo
```

`/bin/sh` is the binary, whose first argument is `-c`, which itself accepts a "command string" as parameter. This is `echo` in the above example. Then there is a third argument: `foo` which is an argument for `/bin/sh`, not for `echo`. That's why in your third example:

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo foo; echo bar'
```

... both are printed. You quoted the argument. Thus: the first argument is `-c`, and the parameter to this argument is `'echo foo; echo bar'` which is interpreted whole as one argument; as the "command string".

Answer (score 3):

The structure `sh -c word` executes only word (in a shell).
Added words mean other things, like argument zero, one, two, etc.:

```
sh -c word zero one two three
```

to keep a command which has spaces as one word, quoting is needed:

```
sh -c 'echo fnord' zero one two three
```

so, this prints all the arguments:

```
$ sh -c 'echo "args=" "$0" "$@"' zero one two three
args = zero one two three
```

#### Examples

In the example you present: `/bin/sh -c echo foo` The first word (after options) is `echo`, that is what is executed. And an echo with no text will print a new-line only, nothing else:

```
$ /bin/sh -c echo foo
```

That is why you do get an empty line.

If you quote the space, you will be executing "one word" (no spaces), as this:

```
$ /bin/sh -c echo\ foo
foo
$ /bin/sh -c "echo foo"
foo
$ /bin/sh -c 'echo foo'
foo
```

#### Conclusion

Keep the executed command as one "word" using quoting.