# Strange 'sh -c' behavior when run through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to run a few commands through `ssh` and getting confused with the behavior of `sh -c`:

```
ssh myhost sh -c 'echo starting; who -b; date; echo $SHELL'
```

Output (note: the echo's output is just a blank line!)

```
         system boot  2016-12-22 20:22
Thu Jan 26 06:12:52 UTC 2017
/bin/bash
```

Without `sh -c` I get the correct output:

```
ssh myhost 'echo starting; who -b; date; echo $SHELL'
```

Output:

```
starting
         system boot  2016-12-22 20:22
Thu Jan 26 06:18:28 UTC 2017
/bin/bash
```

---

Questions:

1. Why doesn't `sh -c` handle the `echo starting` command correctly?  It outputs a blank line.
2. Why is SHELL set to `/bin/bash` even with `sh -c`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple different unintuitive things going on here.

First of all, your command to the remote host is parsed as

```
(sh -c echo starting); who -b; date; echo $SHELL
```

The outer quotes are stripped away leaving you with only `echo starting` run in `sh` which is why `$SHELL` is set to `/bin/bash`.

Secondly, "starting" isn't printed for the reasons stated in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253424

However, you can fix both of these problems by simply wrapping the command in another set of quotes, leaving you with

```
ssh myhost sh -c '"echo starting; who -b ; date; echo $SHELL"'
```

Though I would argue it's more clear if you move the single quotes out to encompass the `sh` command:

```
ssh myhost 'sh -c "echo starting; who -b ; date; echo $SHELL"'
```

Comment: The `$SHELL` would be expanded by the login shell of the remote user as it's between double quotes (and assuming that shell is Bourne-like or csh-like or `fish`). You'd need to escape the `$` if you wanted the `$SHELL` to be expanded by `sh`: `ssh myhost 'sh -c "echo starting; who -b ; date; echo \$SHELL"'`